# AJAX isn't called when button clicked?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Right now my website opens up and the user can select what they want to order. When they want to submit a order i just want to send an email but the email isn't coming through and my page just restarts.

**javascript/AJAX:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function() {
            $('#wholesaleOrderForm').submit(
                function() {
                    if (validateForm()) {
                        $.post("wholesale_form.php",
                            $('#wholesaleOrderForm').serialize(),
                            function(response) {
                                alert('response = ' + response);
                                if (response == "success") {
                                    $('#ajax-msg').html("Thanks for subscribing!");
                                    $('#ajax-msg').style.color = "green";
                                    $('#ajax-msg').hide(5000);
                                } else {
                                    $('#ajax-msg').html("Sorry, there is some error. Please try again.");
                                    $('#ajax-msg').style.color = "red";
                                    $('#ajax-msg').hide(5000);
                                }
                            }
                        );
                        // prevent postback
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    );
</script>
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php

$to = "lazar108@hotmail.com";
    $subject = 'hello';
    $message = "Hello!!";
    $headers = 'From: DoNotReply@COMPANY_EMAIL.com';

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: Define `it's not working`

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Check the return value of `mail`, if it is `true` then the mail server has accepted the mail, so the issue isn't on the PHP part.

Comment: Not sure if is the case, but mail function will not work in Local server.

Comment: Looks like the php is failing. Try testing the php on it's own (not through the AJAX call) and see what happens.

Comment: Please add the form to your question. Looks like the jquery function is not being called.

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable the form's default action with event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 2):

Further to Julaine's suggestion, change these two lines:

```
$('#wholesaleOrderForm').submit(
    function() {
```

to this:

```
$('#wholesaleOrderForm').submit(
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //rest of your code
```

Explanation:

Forms submit by navigating to another page (usually specified in an `action="newpage.php"` attribute of the form tag. Your AJAX code would not have time to complete before the page navigates away. *Note that if an `action=` attribute is not specified, the page just refreshes -- same problem for AJAX.

---

Further suggestions if that doesn't work:

(1) Divide and conquer. Greatly reduce your code until it works, then gradually add the rest back in, fixing the errors as you find them.

(2) Reduce the ajax to its minimum:

```
$('#wholesaleOrderForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("wholesale_form.php", function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });
});
```

**wholesale_form.php**

```
<?php
    echo 'Ajax is working';
```